# GCP Cloud Scheduler run HTTP App Engine Jon one at a time

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, scheduler

Our AppEngine, written in Python, reads conditionally from BigQuery Table and writes to another BigQuery Source Table.

The above App Engine is triggered by a Cloud Scheduler Job every 15 minutes.

A few times there are multiple Cloud Scheduler Jobs running that cause duplicates in the Source Table.

How do we overcome the above, please?

We're expecting the Cloud Job Scheduler to run the Job one at a time

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you want is that a job is not run (or is paused) if another is still running. If this summary is correct, then something you could consider is...

When you start the job, check the DB for a flag. If the flag isn't there, then you set the flag and the job starts running. When the job is done running, it deletes the flag.

In say 15 minutes, when another job tries to start, it checks for the flag. If it's there, it means the job can't run. You can pause it (sleep) for X seconds/minutes (you have to figure out how to back-off). If the flag isn't there, it runs

Comment: Many thanks for this answer, It's a very simple solution :-) Many Thanks once again.